# Using a mobile hotspot as a modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

Do all routers with USB ports for 3G/4G backup connections support all mobile broadband devices? I'm just curious to see if, since I can't get fiber due to my apartment block not being wired for it, using a 4G modem would give better speeds. The hotspot I am looking at is the TP-Link M7350 4G LTE MiFi and I have the ASUS RT-AC51U, so I'm just wondering if I can conntect the two via USB or whether anpther you folks would reccommend an alternate solution

Comment: The answer is "no, they don't all support all devices". The correct way to answer your actual question yourself is to connect the modem to the laptop and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obviously that ASUS RT-AC51U has the feature.I'm not sure TP-Link M7350 4G LTE MiFi if it is supported.
There a quick connect guide for you
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5FjpBiYiXo